# Branches and what they Represent in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to tell me what these branches are for and what they stand for and why they were created?

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/branches

I don't see any notes on any of these new branches that just surfaced lately to tell me as a consumer what is what, what we should use and for what, etc.

The only thing I have found in the docs is the v3-fix which is the ongoing dev branch I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Contributing docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Contributing) for some more info about this.

- `master` - holds the future v4 version of ServiceStack, here's a recent update [describing the changes](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/P3ruPpFZezp)
- `v3` - holds the current **v3.x** of ServiceStack that's currently deployed to NuGet
- `v3-fixes` - is where all external contributions should be made, which is used to merge changes into the `v3` and `v3-fixes` release branches. Although since the main `ServiceStack` project has changed so much, it's unlikely any change can be merged cleanly into both `v3` and `master` anymore - but this convention still applies to the other [ServiceStack repos](https://github.com/ServiceStack/).
- `async` - was an old alpha branch where ServiceStack was changed to be built on ASP.NET's async HttpHandlers, it's now archived for informational blue-print on how new server-side async support should be added.
- `gh-pages` - is a GitHub convention to be able to host a customized website from your repo, initially started to host docs, but was never really used.

Comment: thanks can you please put that in the notes somewhere up front.  These branches are a list not only for contributors but experimental, beta and much more.  Can you please put this list above somewhere up front in the docs closer to that list of downloads.  I have already read the Contributing docs, and they do not cover all these new branches, it only talks about the fixes branch which I already knew of FROM reading that page.  What's lacking is the full list above.  As you guys add new stuff, people are left with ??? what's this or that which we're left with wasted time figuring this all out

Comment: so what branch is "stable" meaning you have released it (frozen it after a final CI build and it is an official release)?.  That would be v3 right?  If so, I just downloaded it and it does not build out of the box.  This is what I've been talking about.  A release branch should never change, but yet I see v3 was just modified 2 days ago which tells me it's still "in flux".  The point is nobody knows what's supposed to work, what's the official working release, etc. if stuff keeps changing and then you have an additional v3-fixes.  It's almost like v3 is still some kind of dev branch.

Comment: why not name "master" v4 - Dev.  Until now master meant nothing to me or anyone so it's like looking at a black hole into nothing, only you guys know what's going on.  Pretty frustrating to anyone.  This stuff should be very discover-able and it's not clear what is what for what.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict branches are never frozen, they get iterated on and then are released, like we did with [v3.9.64 released 2 days ago](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/PpkoW1dmkZ1). Because `master` is `master` it represents the current state of development. But that's it, I'm done now.

Comment: but there are versions that are STABLE.  Your release page is v3.9.60.  And you again talk about an official release (stable version) in yet another area (forum).  Why can't you centralize this stuff, I'm finding tidbits all over from you and how would I be able to just know oh, that piece in the forum, this piece is in the read me, that piece is on this page in the wiki, dude I'm dizzy.  You need to find a way to organize all these messages and stuff better.

Comment: so how do I get v3.9.64?  I want the source for that not the dlls.

Comment: so basically (and tell me if I'm right) the conclusion of the ServiceStack API is that you NuGet down dlls, that's your own option if you want to use this framework.  You can't expect to use the actual source code instead of dlls because it's never stable or working at any given time.  Is that correct?  So basically your API source is exposed but nobody can really rely on it.  They can only rely on what Stack deems "working" and that is in the form of dlls only.  Is that correct?